# Create Vm in WAP using PowerShell, error 400

Tags: powershell, azure-pack

I'm trying to create a VM using PowerShell in Windows Azure Pack.
I've downloaded the subscription, and `Get-WAPackVM` returns the VM's already created.

I've tried running these two scripts:

```
$OSDisk = Get-WAPackVMOSDisk -Name "W2012R2 Template_disk_1"
$SizeProfile = Get-WAPackVMSizeProfile -Name "Template"     
New-WAPackVM -Name "ContosoV073" -OSDisk $OSDisk -VMSizeProfile $SizeProfile
```

and

```
$Credentials = Get-Credential 
$Template = Get-WAPackVMTemplate -Name "Template 1"
New-WAPackVM -Name "VirShits7" -Template $Template -VMCredential $Credentials -Windows
```

Both returns the same error:

```
New-WAPackVM : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

All the Get cmdlets return values, and seem to be correct. 
Anyone know how I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You may reference the page:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj643289.aspx

The page say:
The key properties that you must set on the virtual machine object that is used with the Service Provider Foundation service are as follows: CloudId, StampId, VMTemplateId ,Name.

You may need to assign CloudId and StampId.
I did it by RESTApi and it works.